# Small area of siding where adjacent pieces are not overlapping

Tags: siding

So, in the posted photo, it seems Iike the double black arrow indicates last full row of siding,the blue arrow is a vinyl trim piece up against the wood frieze board, and the red arrow is where there is siding maybe cut to size and these siding pieces are not overlapping. 
￼
Somebody tried to make it better and the Gap is smaller, but the siding is still not overlapping.
￼
I would like to have this fixed to where there is no gap between the adjacent pieces of siding.  What are some thoughts on how this could be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have siding overlapping to shield the house and direct water away. It seems like judging from the picture that the piece is so close to the overhang that the place will be free of water and therefore I would ignore it. If that is not true I would get a wider piece and overlap it with the first real siding piece.

Comment: I agree the overhang will protect the area just fine , the vents are only a couple inches above that if any water were to get in that would be the area to be concerned about , but again the overhang keeps the top dry.